# Instance member 'count' cannot be used on type 'TweetFilterOptions.AllCases'

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am making a swiftUI app where I have an enum. In the View struct I am going to get the number of cases with `var n = TweetFilterOptions.AllCases.count` . But I am getting an error:

```
Instance member 'count' cannot be used on type 'TweetFilterOptions.AllCases' (aka 'Array<TweetFilterOptions>'); did you mean to use a value of this type instead?
```

My codes look like this:

```
enum TweetFilterOptions: Int, CaseIterable{
    case tweets
    case replies
    case likes
    
    var title:String{
        switch self{
        case .tweets:
            return "tweets"
        case .replies:
            return "tweets and replies"
        case .likes:
            return "likes"
        }
    }
}

struct FilterButtonView: View {
    var n = TweetFilterOptions.AllCases.count // Here I am getting the error.
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment:.leading){
            HStack{
                ForEach(TweetFilterOptions.allCases, id:\.self){ options in
                    Text(options.title)
                }
            }
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 300, height: 3)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .animation(.spring())
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get rid of this error and get the number of all cases in the enum?

Comment: It should be TweetFilterOptions.allCases.count

Comment: Yes, it is working, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use .allCases instead of .AllCases. Like this

```
var n = TweetFilterOptions.allCases.count
```